# Add divs below a parent div using jquery

Tags: jquery, addition, html

Here is my parent div,

```
<div id="ResultsDiv" class="resultsdiv">
 <br />
 <span id="EmployeeName" style="font-size:125%;font-weight:bolder;">Pandiyan</span>
 <span style="font-size:100%;font-weight:bolder;padding-left:100px;">Category&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;
 <span>Supervisor</span><br /><br />
 <span id="SalaryBasis" style="font-size:100%;font-weight:bolder;">Salary Basis&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;
 <span>Monthly</span>
 <span style="font-size:100%;font-weight:bolder;padding-left:25px;">Salary&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;
 <span>25,000</span>
 <span style="font-size:100%;font-weight:bolder;padding-left:25px;">Address&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;
 <span>Madurai</span>
</div>
```

[alt text http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/844/divl.jpg](http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/844/divl.jpg)

How to add divs below this parent div using jquery,

```
function Iteratejsondata(HfJsonValue) {
    var jsonObj = eval('(' + HfJsonValue + ')');

    for (var i = 0, len = jsonObj.Table.length; i < len; ++i) {
        var employee = jsonObj.Table[i];

        //Add divs here based on length
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the [insertAfter](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) function:

```
$('<div>' + employee.SomeProperty +'</div>').insertAfter('#ResultsDiv');
```

This will insert a div for each emplyee just after the div#ResultDiv. If you want to insert divs inside the result div you could use the [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method:

```
$('#ResultsDiv').append('<div>' + employee.SomeProperty +'</div>');
```