# Jquery insertAfter() doesn't seem to work for me

Tags: jquery, html, insertafter

I have created a parent div and inserted div's after the parent div using jquery `insertAfter()` method.... What happens is My first record goes to the bottom and next record gets inserted above it....

Here is my function...

```
function Iteratejsondata(HfJsonValue) {
    var jsonObj = eval('(' + HfJsonValue + ')');
    for (var i = 0, len = jsonObj.Table.length; i < len; ++i) {
        var employee = jsonObj.Table[i];
        $('<div  class="resultsdiv"><br /><span id="EmployeeName" style="font-size:125%;font-weight:bolder;">' + employee.Emp_Name + '</span><span style="font-size:100%;font-weight:bolder;padding-left:100px;">Category&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span>' + employee.Desig_Name + '</span><br /><br /><span id="SalaryBasis" style="font-size:100%;font-weight:bolder;">Salary Basis&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span>' + employee.SalaryBasis + '</span><span style="font-size:100%;font-weight:bolder;padding-left:25px;">Salary&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span>' + employee.FixedSalary + '</span><span style="font-size:100%;font-weight:bolder;padding-left:25px;">Address&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span>' + employee.Address + '</span></div>').insertAfter('#ResultsDiv');
    }
}
```

And my result is,

[alt text http://img265.imageshack.us/img265/7646/divresult.jpg](http://img265.imageshack.us/img265/7646/divresult.jpg)

Palani must be next to my parent div but it is at the bottom... Because `insertAfter()`
inserts every record next to the `#ResultsDiv` ... Any suggestion how to insertafter the newly generated div...

**EDIT:**
how to add row color to these divs i used

```
 function Iteratejsondata(HfJsonValue) {
 var jsonObj = JSON.parse(HfJsonValue);
 for (var i = jsonObj.Table.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var employee = jsonObj.Table[i];
    $('<div id="resDiv" class="resultsdiv"><br /><span id="EmployeeName" style="font-size:125%;font-weight:bolder;">' + employee.Emp_Name + '</span><span style="font-size:100%;font-weight:bolder;padding-left:100px;">Category&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span>' + employee.Desig_Name + '</span><br /><br /><span id="SalaryBasis" style="font-size:100%;font-weight:bolder;">Salary Basis&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span>' + employee.SalaryBasis + '</span><span style="font-size:100%;font-weight:bolder;padding-left:25px;">Salary&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span>' + employee.FixedSalary + '</span><span style="font-size:100%;font-weight:bolder;padding-left:25px;">Address&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span>' + employee.Address + '</span></div>').insertAfter('#ResultsDiv');
}
$("#resDiv.resultsdiv:odd").css("background-color", "#F4F4F8");
$("#resDiv.resultsdiv:even").css("background-color", "#EFF1F1");
}
```

But didnt work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse the loop:

```
for (var i = jsonObj.Table.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

Remark: **don't** use `eval`. I would recommend you [JSON.parse](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) instead or if this JSON is coming from an ajax call jQuery should automatically parse it to object.

---

UPDATE:

To add row color to these divs you could try this **outside** the loop:

```
$(".resultsdiv:odd").css("background-color", "#F4F4F8");
$(".resultsdiv:even").css("background-color", "#EFF1F1");
```

Comment: `var jsonObj = JSON.parse(HfJsonValue);`

Comment: Of course: `$('.resultsdiv').hover(function() { alert('hovering'); });`

Comment: @Darin found that too `$(this).css('background-color', '#F00');` inside the function...

Answer (score 1):

You are adding elements *after* the parent element:

```
<div id="ResultsDiv">
</div>
<div class="resultsdiv">...4...</div>
<div class="resultsdiv">...3...</div>
<div class="resultsdiv">...2...</div>
<div class="resultsdiv">...1...</div>
```

but you probably want to add elements *inside* the parent element:

```
<div id="ResultsDiv">
  <div class="resultsdiv">...1...</div>
  <div class="resultsdiv">...2...</div>
  <div class="resultsdiv">...3...</div>
  <div class="resultsdiv">...4...</div>
</div>
```

Use the `appendTo` method instead of the `insertAfter` method.

#### Update:

You are adding several elements with the same id, which is not legal. Just use the class to target the elements:

```
$(".resultsdiv:odd").css("background-color", "#F4F4F8");
$(".resultsdiv:even").css("background-color", "#EFF1F1");
```

Comment: @Guffa look at this question you ll know what i am doing
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498179/add-divs-below-a-parent-div-using-jquery

Comment: @Pandiya: Then your "parent" element is really just the first sibling. Append the elements to the parent of the first element instead.

Comment: thats y i used `insertAfter()` method.. Is it correct or am i missing something here?

Comment: @Pandiya: If you use the `insertAfter` method you can only insert elements next to the "parent" element. If you add a real parent element you can add elements at the end of the list.